# Kernel of $q(x,y,z)=2x^2-4xy+2z^2-4xz+4yz$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some problems when calculating the kernel of the quadratic form $q(x,y,z)=2x^2-4xy+2z^2-4xz+4yz$: indeed, I get $Ker=\{(x,y,z)|x^2-y^2=0\}$, which results in a 2-dimensional kernel. Could you show me the correct method for finding the kernel of a quadratic form?

Comment: How did you find this kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, dealing with vector spaces, etc, we expect linear things to happen. Your kernel can't be right, it is not even a vector space.

Note that we have $$q(x,y,z) = \begin{pmatrix} x & y & z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -2 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}.$$ Calling $Q$ this middle matrix above, by definition we have $\ker q := \ker Q$. Let's find $\ker Q$. If $(x,y,z) \in \ker Q$, we must have $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -2 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},$$ which is equivalent to solving the system: $$\begin{cases}2x-2y-2z &= 0 \\ -2x+2z &= 0 \\ -2x+2y+2z &= 0 \end{cases}.$$
I will find it by row reducing the matrix $Q$, as follows: $$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -2 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix} \stackrel{\begin{matrix}L_2:=L_2+L_1 \\ L_3:= L_3+L_1\end{matrix}}{\sim} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 & -2 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} \stackrel{L_1:= L_1/2}{\sim} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$ which gives us $y = 0$ from the second row, and substituting in the first row, $x-z = 0$. So we actually have: $$(x,y,z) = (x,0,x) = x(1,0,1),$$ then the kernel is the line generated by $(1,0,1)$. And this is indeed coherent, since we can see that the matrix $Q$ has rank $2$, and so $$3 = \dim \ker Q + {\rm rank \ }Q \implies \dim \ker Q = 1.$$

Comment: @user62029 In the other question I didn't do the calculations because I thought that you knew the procedure to be done and the problem was with specific calculations. Please say if I can help you any further.

Comment: +1, neat. Perhaps should mention that $Q$ needs to be symmetric.

Comment: Thank you for your help. One more thing: you said "If $(x,y,z) \in \ker Q$, we must have $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -2 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$" Could you clarify why did you write that matrix (and therefore that system) and not something like
$q(x,y,z) = \begin{pmatrix} x & y & z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -2 & 2 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Also, why does the rank-nullity theorem apply to quadratic forms as well?

Comment: Recall that by *definition*, $\ker q := \ker Q$. I only used the quadatric form to get the matrix $Q$. From there on it is all about matrix theory. I'm finding the kernel of the matrix $Q$. And I used rank-nullity for the *matrix* $Q$, not for a quadratic form.

Comment: @IvoTerek I see. But I don't think that we've given that definition during lecture. Could you point out a reference book where I can find this?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it was in a brazilian book, "Algebra Linear", from José Luiz Boldrini, but I don't think there are versions in english of this book..